# I need help figuring out why my regex does not match with what I am looking for

Tags: r, regex, boolean

I am working on a R script aiming to check if a data.frame is correctly made and contains the right information at the right place.
I need to make sure a row contains the right information, so I want to use a regular expression to compare with each case of said row.

I thought maybe it did not work because I compared the `regex` to the value by calling the value directly from the table, but it did not work.

I used regex101.com to make sure my regular expression was correct, and it matched when the test string was put between quotes.

Then I added `as.character()` to the value, but it came out FALSE.

To sum up, the regex works on regex101.com, but never did on my R script

```
test = c("b40", "b40")
".[ab][0-8]{2}." == test[1]
FALSE
```

I expect the output to be `TRUE`, but it is always `FALSE`

Comment: Use `grep` instead of `==`

Comment: I did try grep(), the output is integer(0)

Comment: Use `grepl` not `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` is for fixed full string match and not used for substring match.  For that, we can use `grep`

```
grepl("^[ab][0-8]{2}", test[1])
#[1] TRUE
```

Here, we match either 'a' or 'b' at the start (`^`) of the string followed by two digits ranging from 0 to 8 (if it should be at the end - use `$`)

Comment: grepl() worked, I guess I made two errors : using == and also putting "." at the beginning and at the end. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @MartinFaucher  The `.` is a metacharacter that matches any character if not escaped (`\\`)